# show image if new record since users last visit

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to have a image that will change if an sql record is created since the last visit of that registerd user and another image if criteria not met.

The record table is `matningar` with a date field `datum`. 
Maybe the below code something close to achieving this?!

```
    <?php

    $stmt = "SELECT * FROM matningar WHERE `datum` > date("F j, Y, g:i a", $database-    >getLastUserRegisteredDate()";
    $result=mysql_query($stmt);
    foreach($result as $rec){
    echo "<img src=\"images/somepicture.png\" />";
    } 
    ?>
```

Would really appreciate some input on how to proceed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could count the records returned and use conditional statements to determine what image you want to display. For example using your code:

```
/* Using a mysql query which is discouraged and will be depreceated in future */

      // declare variables
      $i = 0;
      $lastRegisteredDate = date("F j, Y, g:i a", $database->getLastUserRegisteredDate());

      // declare statement string
      $stmt = "SELECT * FROM matningar WHERE `datum` > $lastRegisteredDate";

      // execute query
      $result=mysql_query($stmt);

      // make sure query executed properly
      if (!$result) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
      }

      // manually count the number of results
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $i++;
      }

      // display image based on conditions
      if($i == 0) {
        // display one image
      }
      else {
        // display another image
      }
```

Just as a side note mysql functions are going to be depreceated in upcoming PHP releases   so I would start looking at using the PDO or mysqli libraries for mysql queries.

```
/* Using the PDO library */

  // declare variables
  $i = 0;
  $lastRegisteredDate = date("F j, Y, g:i a", $database->getLastUserRegisteredDate());

  // declare database handler
  $DBH = new PDO( "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass );

  // prepare query
  $STH = $DBH->prepare( "SELECT * FROM matningar WHERE `datum` > ?" );

  // execute query
  $STH->execute( array( $lastRegisteredDate ) );

  // set fetch mode  
  $STH->setFetchMode( PDO::FETCH_OBJ );

  // manually count the number of results
  while ( $row = $STH->fetch() ) {
    $i++;
  }

  // display image based on conditions
  if($i == 0) {
    // display one image
  }
  else {
    // display another image
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! If I would only want to choose records containing a specific value, could I just replace the "SELECT * FROM" with "SELECT value FROM". I am so thankful for people like you guys who are willing to help a beginner like me! :) On the sidenote, which would you recommend to start learning, PDO or mysqli?

Comment: You would use "SELECT column FROM table WHERE column = desired value" to select a specific value. I like PDO but really haven't used mysqli too much. The opinions are pretty split as to what to use. If my answer helped an up vote or accepting the answer would help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Great! I'll definitely look into that!

Comment: -1 for not changing that ugly `$stmt` string. Also, using a foreach after a mysql_query like that didn't work last time I checked. And that `elseif` is unnecessary, `else` would be enough.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Thanks for the critique. I must have not had my coffe that day. I revised the post, hopefully that's a little better quality.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the best approach to this would be to store the updated record time using this method when creating your table.

```
updated TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

This way when you SELECT records from the database and you're displaying them on the page, you can do something like so to display separate images based on current users last visit:

```
foreach($results as $record) {
  if($record['updated'] > $currentUser->getLastVisited()) {
    echo "<img .... />"; // Has been modified since last visit
  } else {
    echo "<img .... />"; // Not been modified since last visit
  }
  // Display rest of this record
}
```

Comment: +1 for recommending `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, and +1 for a nice foreach-loop. (Although `fetch_all` must be called on the result set - assuming PDO or mysqli is used)